# Issue with Content by Search Webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

I'm facing an unusual issue with content by search webpart in SP2013.

On alternate page refresh, the search result is not rendered in the page.
On first page load the search result is rendered, then I tried to edit the page, now the result is not rendered in the page though the test query is returning values as expected.

Any suggestion/leads to get rid of this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in edit page mode, cswp will not render. Apply changes and click Save in ribbon and then it will render properly.